# Deleting Old data using shell script based on date

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've lot of files created in the data format (2012-10-11). How can I delete the files based on date. I mean the files less than 3 months should be deleted. It should be done in shell script. I searched in google and used tools available in ubuntu software center. And also searched for scripts in launchpad. Could Anyone help..

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

find . -ctime +90 -exec rm -i '{}' \;

you can also remove the '-i' (ask before delete) if you feel very lucky